# Angular 2 Reactive Forms use controls or get?

Tags: angular

In templates I have seen both approaches:

```
myForm.controls.StartDate.value
```

and

```
myForm.get('StartDate').value
```

I thought 'controls' is now the approach going forward but when doing `ng build -prod` this breaks the build. What is the one to use for best practice and that won't break the build?

Comment: Why a downvote? It would be more helpful if you could say as to why it deserves a downvote. This is a perfectly fine question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms and they use `.get()` on `FormGroup` and `.controls` (in template) on `FormArray`. Maybe that's the way, because on `FormArray` has non-named controls.

As stated in https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive, there is no difference between using `.get()` and `.controls` but that first one does error handling for you.

In my projects I use `.get()` on FormGroup and it works just fine. Can't tell you which approach is better nowadays. If `.controls` works with IDE prompts it should be the best - if it doesn't it's hard to tell the difference.

Under the hood, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L37
`.get()` uses `.find()` and `.find()` uses `.controls`. So it should be okay to use both. Using any of them should not break your prod build.

Comment: This is great thanks for your answer. Using controls does break it the build but I'll attempt to use it as mentioned in your first paragraph. There have been other scenerios using Angular 2 which break the build so I have had to resort to using 'ng build --prod --aot=false'